# NSDictionary - Printing Array

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sorting, macos, nsdictionary

This site is great I'm getting alot of replies , so I have tried to code what I had problems with before here it is

```
NSMutableArray *sort = [NSMutableArray arraywithArray:[dic allValues]]; 

for(NSString *s in sort){
    [Purchases appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",s]]; 
} 
textview.text = Purchases;
```

The output's order still does not appear like it does when i Open the Plist file... 
Also a side note is it possible to write and open plist files in your Resources folder instead...

Thanks for the help!

Edit:

```
2010-02-12 23:54:35 -0500 
2010-02-12 23:29:11 - 0500 
2010-02-12 23:54:42 - 0500 
2010-02-12 23:54:58 - 0500
```

thats the Order I get ^^

but when I open the plist file the order is:

```
2010-02-12 23:29:11 -0500 
2010-02-12 23:54:35 -0500 
2010 02-12 23:54:42 - 0500 
2010 02-12 23:54:58 - 0500
```

^^ Thats the order I want except in descending

Comment: Can you show the order you expect and the order you're getting?  I have a feeling you might want to sort the array of keys from the dictionary, not the array of values, and then use the sorted keys to access the dictionary.

Comment: You are going to lose all ordering when you store things in a dictionary.

Comment: Yeah I would like to sort the keys which are date + time and I would like to show it in descending order (latest date time first)...

Answer (score 3):

`[dic allValues]` does not return keys in any sort of reliable order.  It's using a set underneath, which means it's unordered.

If you're looking for a dictionary that also maintains insertion order, check out `CHOrderedDictionary` that's part of the [CHDataStructures framework](http://cocoaheads.byu.edu/code/chdatastructures).

Answer (score 2):

As specified [in the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdictionary), the order of the values is not specified. So you need to sort the keys before the iteration, with one of the sort methods of [NSArray](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsarray).

For example, this code will sort the string values in the ascending order:

```
NSArray *sort = [[dic allValues] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];

for(NSString *s in sort){
    [Purchases appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",s]]; 
} 
textview.text = Purchases;
```

Refer to the [NSArray documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsarray) to learn about the various way on sorting an array (selector, blocks, etc).

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to show it in descending order (latest date time first)...

Then you need to [sort it](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:). You cannot count on a dictionary giving you its contents in any order, not even the order you loaded or inserted them in.